# My Android Finger paint app sends paint to irregular places on image

Tags: android, paint

In my Android Finger Paint app I used two view's imageview backside and paintview on top, it's working fine for painting and erasing.  But after saving the real painting position is changed.

*removed dead links to images*

**Code is**

```
public MyView(Context c)  {
    super(c);
    //mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,bw,bh,true);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw,bh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
}
@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
} 

myimage.setOnTouchListener(this);
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView myimage = (ImageView) v;
    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                /////// limiting  the panning 
                matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                float currentY = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                float currentX = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float currentScale = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                float currentHeight = height * currentScale;
                float currentWidth = width * currentScale;
                float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                float newX = currentX+dx;
                float newY = currentY+dy;   
                RectF drawingRect = new RectF(newX, newY, newX+currentWidth, newY+currentHeight);
                float diffUp = Math.min(viewRect.bottom-drawingRect.bottom, viewRect.top-drawingRect.top);
                float diffDown = Math.max(viewRect.bottom-drawingRect.bottom, viewRect.top-drawingRect.top);
                float diffLeft = Math.min(viewRect.left-drawingRect.left, viewRect.right-drawingRect.right);
                float diffRight = Math.max(viewRect.left-drawingRect.left, viewRect.right-drawingRect.right);
                if(diffUp > 0 ){ dy +=diffUp; }
                if(diffDown < 0){ dy +=diffDown; }  
                if( diffLeft> 0){ dx += diffLeft; }
                if(diffRight < 0){dx += diffRight; }
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
            } 
            else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                float currentScale = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                // limit zoom
                if (scale * currentScale > maxZoom) {
                    scale = maxZoom / currentScale; 
                }
                else if(scale * currentScale < minZoom){
                    scale = minZoom / currentScale; 
                }
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    myimage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

// Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging 
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                      "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode ==   MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
    }

    //Determine the space between the first two fingers
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    // Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers 
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: add your ontouchlistner code of imageview. The problem happens when you draw, pan and then save.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position does *not* change! If you look closely at your linked images, you'll see that your fingerpainting does not move relative to the corner of the photo. In other words, you are saving the drawings' positions relative to the screen rather than relative to the current scroll position of the photo.

When you save, you have to take into account the fact that the background photo is cropped and/or scaled.

Comment: @raj: When you go to transfer the fingerpainting you have to transfer it to whatever X and Y position you have the background scrolled to.

Comment: at starting of this activity it show's only image (possible to panning and zooming ) after press button we allow painting on image. painting image is transparent view. we can't move by X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a paint/erase mode. When in paint/erase mode, disallow panning and zooming. When paint/erase is turned off, get the drawing cache and set it to imageview. Now the changes are permanently in the bitmap. So you can pan/zoom now and again enter the paint/erase mode to edit further.

Comment: two different modes how, this is the code for Menu : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38493970/Full.java

Comment: Alternative solution, have the paintview zoom and pan along with the imageview. how do you save the bitmap?

Comment: paint view not having zoom and panning, only imageview having this char's